# Dynamically create Vue Component on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list of orders which I am populating via the `orders` array. Each of these orders have a functionality where the user can edit these orders. I am trying to generate a vuetify dialog box component when the user clicks on the edit button which will have the default data from that order which the user can choose to edit. So far I have tried this,

```html
<tbody class="items">
  <tr v-for="order in orders" :key="order.name">
    <td>{{ order.fullname }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.phone }}</td>
    <!-- <td>{{ order.orderQuantity }}</td> -->
    <td>{{ order.quantity }}</td>
    <td v-if="order.status == true">
      <v-chip small outlined class="ma-2 chip" color="green">delivered</v-chip>
    </td>
    <td v-if="order.status == false">
      <v-chip small outlined class="ma-2 chip" color="red">in progress</v-chip>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- <component v-bind:is="component"></component> -->
      <!-- <EditOrder></EditOrder> -->
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="290">
        <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn icon color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> Open Dialog </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline"> Use Google's location service? </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>{{ phone }}</v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog = false"> Disagree </v-btn>
            <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog = false"> Agree </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

but this generates n instances of the dialog box before the actual components loads. I also tried using async components but couldn't figure out where I was wrong.

This is what I think should happen;
When the user clicks on the "edit order" button, a dialog box component with the default order details for that particular order must be automatically generated and destroyed.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the `dialog` part to a separate component
2. In the `parent` component, use it once at the beginning with `dialog=false` to be hidden initially
3. Add a `data` attribute `orderToEdit` which will be a `prop` to the child component
4. For each order in the list, add an edit button that would call a method when clicked passing the `order`
5. In this method, set `orderToEdit` to the passed `order` of the clicked item and set `dialog=true` to show it with the custom values

```js
const dialogmodel = Vue.component('btn', {
  template: '#dialogmodel',
  props: { order: Object, value: Boolean },
  computed: {
    dialog: {
      get () { return this.value; },
      set (value) { this.$emit('close', value); }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: { dialogmodel },
  data: () => ({
    orders: [
      { name:"1", fullname:"fullname1", address:"address1", phone:"phone1", quantity:"quantity1", status:false },
      { name:"2", fullname:"fullname2", address:"address2", phone:"phone2", quantity:"quantity2", status:true }
    ],
    dialog:false,
    orderToEdit: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    closeDialog(value) { this.dialog = value; },
    editOrder(order) { this.orderToEdit = order; this.dialog = true; }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<template id="dialogmodel">
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290" persistent>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">
          {{ order.fullname }}
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text> {{ order.address }} </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="$emit('close')">
            Disagree
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<v-app id="app">
  <div>
    <dialogmodel v-model="dialog" :order="orderToEdit" @close="closeDialog" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody class="items">
        <tr v-for="order in orders" :key="order.name">
          <td>{{ order.fullname }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.address }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.quantity }}</td>
          <td v-if="order.status == true">
            <v-chip small outlined class="ma-2 chip" color="green">delivered</v-chip>
          </td>
          <td v-if="order.status == false">
            <v-chip small outlined class="ma-2 chip" color="red">in progress</v-chip>
          </td>
          <td>
            <v-btn @click="editOrder(order)">Edit</v-btn>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to have a central popup being filled with the data of the order you selected to edit? In that case you can simply have a single component for the edit popup (instead of adding them to your v-for).

You can do it like this:

1. When clicking on 'edit', set a data property 'orderIndexToEdit' to the index of the order in the v-for
2. have a single dialog box that becomes visible when 'orderIndexToEdit' is truethy using v-if or v-show
3. Create a computed property that returns the correct order from the orders array, based on the index stored in the 'orderIndexToEdit' variable.
4. Use that computed property to populate the dialog box.

Let me know whether this helps!

Comment: so i have an issue. For the first order, the popup works just fine, but it just doesn't show up on the second or any other order. For the dialog box component, I am using this directive `v-if="orderProp != null"`. I am modifying orderProp with the order id on the click event for the "edit order" button/